# Unable to use USE_ICC_AUTH_WITH_DEVICE_IDENTIFIER permission signed Android app

Tags: android, security, android-permissions, telephonymanager, imei

for my use cases I needed to extract non-resettable hardware information like IMEI, MAC from android devices.

As per the android docs for getting IMEI
https://developer.android.com/reference/android/telephony/TelephonyManager#getImei(int)

It says the method can be invoked if one of the following requirements is met. and I am trying to satisfy.
If the calling app has been granted the [USE_ICC_AUTH_WITH_DEVICE_IDENTIFIER](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/Manifest.permission#USE_ICC_AUTH_WITH_DEVICE_IDENTIFIER) permission.

As per permission API document https://developer.android.com/reference/android/Manifest.permission#USE_ICC_AUTH_WITH_DEVICE_IDENTIFIER this permission has protection level signature or apops

So, I am going ahead with signature protection level. So, I am creating a signed app and running on my andriod device google pixel 5A which runs on Android 12.

when I am running this code I am facing "The user 10240 does not meet the requirements to access device identifiers." security exception

```
2022-06-30 12:09:53.703 23348-23348/com.android.dataextraction E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    Process: com.android.dataextraction, PID: 23348
    java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.android.dataextraction/com.android.dataextraction.LauncherActivity}: java.lang.SecurityException: getImeiForSlot: The user 10240 does not meet the requirements to access device identifiers.
        at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3635)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3792)
        at android.app.servertransaction.LaunchActivityItem.execute(LaunchActivityItem.java:103)
        at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.executeCallbacks(TransactionExecutor.java:135)
        at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.execute(TransactionExecutor.java:95)
        at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:2210)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:106)
        at android.os.Looper.loopOnce(Looper.java:201)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:288)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:7839)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
        at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:548)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1003)
     Caused by: java.lang.SecurityException: getImeiForSlot: The user 10240 does not meet the requirements to access device identifiers.
        at android.os.Parcel.createExceptionOrNull(Parcel.java:2425)
        at android.os.Parcel.createException(Parcel.java:2409)
        at android.os.Parcel.readException(Parcel.java:2392)
        at android.os.Parcel.readException(Parcel.java:2334)
        at com.android.internal.telephony.ITelephony$Stub$Proxy.getImeiForSlot(ITelephony.java:12142)
        at android.telephony.TelephonyManager.getImei(TelephonyManager.java:2088)
        at android.telephony.TelephonyManager.getImei(TelephonyManager.java:2043)
        at com.android.dataextraction.LauncherActivity.onCreate(LauncherActivity.java:44)
        at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:8051)
        at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:8031)
        at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1329)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3608)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3792) 
        at android.app.servertransaction.LaunchActivityItem.execute(LaunchActivityItem.java:103) 
        at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.executeCallbacks(TransactionExecutor.java:135) 
        at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.execute(TransactionExecutor.java:95) 
        at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:2210) 
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:106) 
        at android.os.Looper.loopOnce(Looper.java:201) 
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:288) 
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:7839) 
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
        at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:548) 
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1003)
```

and I am using a signed app for testing. here is my build. Gradle configs

```
signingConfigs {
        config {
            keyAlias 'AndroidKey'
            keyPassword '**********'
            storeFile file('../android.jks')
            storePassword '********'
        }
    }

buildTypes {
        
        debug {
            signingConfig signingConfigs.config
            debuggable true
        }
    }
```

There is no problem with signing the app.

I am not sure why signature protection level is not allowing me to access device identifiers

Answer (score 0):

Take a second look at definition of signature protection

> A permission that the system grants only if the requesting application
> is signed with the same certificate as the application that declared
> the permission. If the certificates match, the system automatically
> grants the permission without notifying the user or asking for the
> user's explicit approval.

Unless your app is signed with Google's keystore (same keystore as the provider signing your firmware), it cannot get access to signature-level permission.

Comment: you mean only google can access that permission?

Comment: or my firmware provider

Comment: those are inbuilt permissions comes with android. The above one has been added in API level 31.
we declare the permission which our app requires in manifest.xml file

Comment: any app signed with the same key as the app declaring the permission can use it, in this case (for Pixel 5A), it's likely Google and the OEMs. This guy did a pretty good job at explaining that https://android.stackexchange.com/a/218173/255055